# Catch PNG file before download in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a valid event in the browser to catch image file from memory before download and send it to some API?

I generate a print of leaflet map by using leaflet print plugin. This plugin downloads image but I need to send the image to nodeJS server for making PDF document.

Is this even possible to do in JavaScript?

With this extension, image is generated on client not on server
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-easyprint

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do?  "catch image file from memory before download", what do you mean by this?  You're downloading from where?  What do you mean by "catch"... what is preventing you from just running whatever code you need now?

Comment: What you can do is load the image while it's hidden. Do your stuff on the onload event and then make it visible.

Comment: I had found a solution, you can check how I had handled this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by using dom-to-image package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image

Dom is converted to blob or other image format and file is not downloaded explicitly.

The file can be saved manually by using a file saver extension

https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

So, in the end, code for this look like

```
  let map = document.getElementById('map');

  domtoimage.toBlob(map)
        .then(function (blob) {
            saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

No. JavaScript is client-side, unless you're running it on the server which you're almost certainly not.